# What is the difference between template in ZCML and ViewPageTemplateFile

Tags: python, plone, zope, zcml

When creating a [BrowserView](http://developer.plone.org/views/browserviews.html) in Plone, I know that I may optionally configure a template with **ZCML** like so:

```
<configure

    xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser"
    >

    <browser:page
        …
        class=".foo.FooView"
        template="foo.pt"
        …
        />

</configure>
```

Or alternatively in code:

```
# foo.py
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile
from zope.publisher.browser import BrowserPage


class FooView(BrowserPage):
    """
    My View
    """

    def __call__(self):
        return ViewPageTemplateFile('foo.pt')(self)
```

Is there any difference between the two approaches? They both appear to yield the same result.

**Sub-question**: I know there is a `BrowserView` class one can import, but conventionally everyone uses `BrowserPage`. What if any significant differences exist between the two classes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Note: To be fully equivalent to ZCML you should set the `index` variable to specify which template you are using. That way the TTW customization will work too.

```
# foo.py
from Products.Five.browser.pagetemplatefile import ViewPageTemplateFile
from zope.publisher.browser import BrowserPage
class FooView(BrowserPage):
    index = ViewPageTemplateFile('foo.pt')
```

One other pattern you can use with a browser view is adding an update method.

```
class FooView(BrowserPage):
    index = ViewPageTemplateFile('foo.pt')
    def __call__(self):
        self.update()
        return self.index()

    def update(self):
        self.portal_catalog = ...  # initialize code
```

But this is not the question.

---

So what is the difference? **There is no difference**. A browser view must be a callable. The ZCML directive builds this callable in a way the object has an index which must return the rendered page.

But creating the template on each call (your example) there is one difference:
you are creating a new instance of the template on each call of the browser view. 
This is not the case with class variable.

One last option: You don't need a class argument in the directive

```
<configure xmlns:browser="http://namespaces.zope.org/browser">
  <browser:page
    …
    template="foo.pt"
    …
    />
</configure>
```

For more information, you should read [the code of the directive](http://svn.zope.org/%2acheckout%2a/zope.browserpage/trunk/src/zope/browserpage/metadirectives.py?content-type=text%2Fplain&rev=127196), which uses [SimpleViewClass where src is the template name](http://svn.zope.org/%2acheckout%2a/zope.browserpage/trunk/src/zope/browserpage/simpleviewclass.py?content-type=text%2Fplain&rev=126060).

Comment: Please don't use URL shorterners in posts here, there is absolutely no need to and obscures what you are linking to.

Comment: Hi would like but svn.zope.org urls where not recognized as url becaused of the * in it. Thanks for the edit

Comment: Right, when used as a plain URL (not as a link) the paired `*` asterixes are interpreted as markdown for 'italics'.

Answer (score 7):

In Plone, you can customize the template TTW (via `portal_view_customizations`) only when the template is registered explicitly (e.g. using ZCML or Grok-directives).

If you define template only in your `__call__`, you won't see it in `portal_view_customizations`.

Also, I'd guess that loading template within a method would reload it from the disk for every view instance (every request).

Comment: Oh, just skip to @toutpt's answer. I was not aware that the required magic for TTW customizations was just placing defining template as "index" class variable.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, there is **no difference**. The ZCML directive generates a ViewClass with a `ViewPageTemplateFile` and renders the template on a `__call__`. See `zope.browserpage.metaconfigure.page` lines 132, 151.

That is exactly the same you do in your example: you explicitly instantiate the template in your `__call__` method.

As to the subquestion: From my understanding, the significant differences are not apparent in the context of Zope2/Plone. Based on the interface (`zope.publisher.interfaces.browser.IBrowserPage`), the BrowserPage is the base class you want to inherit from, since it implements `__call__` and `browserDefault`. Yet, it does not seem to matter if you use `BrowserPage` or `BrowserView` with Plone.